# Unity error: Failed to find entry-points: showing up after importing previous scripts, and error doesn't lead anywhere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Failed to find entry-points:
Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
  at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00105] in <ebb9e4250ed24cbfa42055e3532ef311>:0 
  at zzzUnity.Burst.CodeGen.AssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name) [0x00039] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 
  at Burst.Compiler.IL.AssemblyLoader.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name) [0x00079] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 
  at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.EntryPointMethodFinder.FindEntryPoints (System.String[] rootAssemblyNames, Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheRuntime.HashCacheAssemblyStore assemblyStore, Burst.Compiler.IL.AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, Burst.Compiler.IL.NativeCompilerOptions options, Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.ProfileDelegate profileCallback, System.Boolean includeRootAssemblyReferences, System.Boolean splitTargets, Burst.Compiler.IL.Helpers.DebugLogWriter debugWriter) [0x00055] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 
  at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.FindMethodsJob.Execute (Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.CompilerServerJobExecutionContext context) [0x00133] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 

While compiling job:
```

I have unity version **2021.3.21f1** along with the latest version of burst installed
I created a new project and in that, I imported some of my previous scripts, it gave this error
at first I thought my .net sdk was broken as it was referring to `'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0,`
So I reinstalled the latest version, restarted the application but to no avail,
then created a new project and imported the same scripts again just to make sure, still showing the same error
and when I double click on the error, it doesn't lead anywhere
I don't understand what's causing this error, any insights?

Comment: I had this same issue in Unity Version 2022.2.13f1 but resolved this issue by disabling Burst Compilation.

Go to `Edit > Project Settings` and under **Burst AOT Settings** uncheck `Enable Burst Compilation`.

Hope this resolves this issue for you as well!

Comment: hey @Jay I tried it and restarted the editor just to make sure, but it was still the same

Comment: Disabling it is a workaround; not a solution, @Jay.  From ChatGPT4: "Disabling Burst will mean your code will run without its optimizations, which might be fine for simpler or less performance-critical applications. But for complex or computation-heavy applications, particularly those that could benefit from parallel processing (multithreading), the benefits of Burst are quite significant."